# SQL - update multiple columns to null based on some where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to construct a SQL statement that performs the following:

For a specific row of a specific table, for all columns where a value = '{}" , make the value NULL

For example:

table XYZ:

```
"col_id"    "col2"  "col3"  "col4"  "col5"

1234        {}       {}     PDQ      ABC
5678        {DO}     {RE}   DEF      HIJ
5678        {MI}     {}   ABC      PDQ
```

If I want: for table XYZ, where col_id = 1234, make all columns with value {} null,

the result would be:

```
"col_id"    "col2"  "col3"  "col4"  "col5"

1234        NULL     NULL     PDQ      ABC
5678        {DO}     {RE}   DEF      HIJ
5678        {MI}     {}   ABC      PDQ
```

Grateful for any assistance. Thank you.

Comment: `set col2 = case col2 when '{}' then null else col2 end, col3 = case col3 when '{}' then null else col3 end,...`

Comment: @BryanDellinger  thanks, but is there a way to do it without calling out each column explicitly? I have a lot of columns and the table may evolve. I was hoping to keep it more genertic and flexible.

Comment: @BryanDellinger Or can you add something to show me how to constraint to a specific row at least? Thanks again!

Comment: @BryanDellinger ok this worked. I figured out your shorthand,,, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NULLIF](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF):

```
UPDATE XYZ set col2 = NULLIF(col2, '{}') ... where customer_id = 1234`
```

Any existing value that is = '{}' will be converted to `NULL`. `UPDATE` needs the columns that are updated to be specified so you cannot get out of naming them.

Comment: Adrian, I am not really following part of your answer. where you have value, do you mean column name??

Comment: Yes, I will change the answer to reflect.

Comment: thanks! works great. A little simpler than Bryans answer (I appreciate both!)

Comment: Mostly it was about the fact that  `NULLIF` exists and is a handy function.

Answer (score 0):

For a variable set of columns you should use dynamic query by a function like

```
create or replace function update_columns(id int) returns varchar as
$$
DECLARE
    column_name text;
    set_clause text;
    r_count int;    
    query text;
BEGIN
    FOR column_name IN select i.column_name  FROM information_schema.columns i 
    WHERE table_schema = 'public' and i.column_name !='id' AND table_name   = 'xyz' LOOP
        set_clause:= concat(set_clause, column_name||'=NULLIF('||column_name||', ''{}''), ');
    END LOOP;
    set_clause:=left(set_clause,-2);
    query:= 'UPDATE xyz set '|| set_clause||' where id='||id::varchar;
    RAISE NOTICE '%', query;        
    execute query;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS r_count = ROW_COUNT;    
    return 'Rows affected ='||r_count;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Then execute

```
select update_columns(1234);
```